# ASP.NET MVC: How do I link correctly to my Delete method using Html.BeginForm?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So far I came up with this:

```
<ul class="menu" id="@Model[i].VideoId">
                    <li class="menu-item">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Video", FormMethod.Post, new { id = Model[i].Id }))
                        {
                            @Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Delete)
                            <button class="btn btn-link" type="submit">Delete</button>
                        }
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Edit </a> </li>
                </ul>
```

But it doesn't work. My controller is Video and the method is Delete, which takes an id parameter and deletes by id from the database.

Comment: Could you show you controller action delete please?

Comment: HttpGet method is the default HTTP verb for an action. Can you please use HttpPost and check. Also, yeah, it would be great if you can share your code of delete action.